# Java updating Table view cell values from another class

Tags: java, javafx, java-8

I am trying to change one of my columns and its cell values from another class however i keep getting a null pointer exception when java try's to execute that line `OverviewController.getOverviewController.returnStatusColumn.setCellValueFactory(
    cellData -> cellData.getValue().getStatusProperty());`, I have removed all irreverent code

TableView Class:

```
@FXML 
private TableView<Task> taskTable;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Task, String> statusColumn;

private final static OverviewController controller = new OverviewController 
();


public static OverviewController getOverviewController() {
    return controller;
}


public void setMainApp(MainApp mainApp) {
    this.mainApp = mainApp;
    taskTable.setItems(mainApp.getTaskData());
    taskTable.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
    taskTable.setPlaceholder(new Label(""));
}

public TableView<taskTable> returnTasks() {
    return taskTable;
}

public TableColumn<taskTable, String> returnStatusColumn() {
    return statusColumn;
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        statusColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> 
cellData.getValue().getStatusProperty());
}

@FXML
public void createTask(ActionEvent event) throws InterruptedException, 
IOException, ParseException {
    thread = new MyThread();
    thread.main(null);

    statusColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> 
cellData.getValue().getStatusRunningProperty());
    statusColumn.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: green; -fx-font-weight: bold;");
    taskTable.refresh();
}

@FXML
public void stopTasks() {
    statusColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> 
cellData.getValue().getStatusProperty());
    statusColumn.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: red; -fx-font-weight: bold;");
    taskTable.refresh();
}
```

This class works fine when i want to update the table columns, if i click stop tasks method (which is linked to a button) the status column gets updated to the stop label which i want to do, same with start tasks method.

Random class where i want to update the Table view status column:

```
public class UpdateTable {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    OverviewController.getOverviewController.returnStatusColumn.setCellValueFactory(
    cellData -> cellData.getValue().getStatusProperty());
    OverviewController.getOverviewController().returnTasks().refresh();
    }

}
```

TableView Data:

```
//Status Information
private final SimpleStringProperty status;
private final SimpleStringProperty statusRunning;


public Task() {
    this(null, null);
}

    public Task() {
        this.statusRunning = new SimpleStringProperty("Running");
        this.status= new SimpleStringProperty("Stop");
    }

    public StringProperty getStatusProperty( ) {
        return status;
    }

    public StringProperty getStatusRunningProperty( ) {
        return statusRunning;
    }

}
```

If i ran the random class it will lead to a null pointer exception in particular this line: 
`OverviewController.getOverviewController().returnStatusColumn().setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getStatusProperty());`

Have i done this completely the wrong way? I just want to be able to update the Table view column cells from a different class.

Comment: a general rule: if you seem to need static fields you are doing something wrong, always (as in 99.999999%)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're doing this the wrong way.

You don't use a `Application` subclass anywhere which needs to be used as entry point of your application (assuming you're not using `JFXPanel` or `Platform.startup`). Furthermore you access the column as first statement in your program which means there's no way the `statusColumn` field is initialized.

Also usually there shouldn't be a need to involve any class but the controller class for initializing the `cellValueFactory`. Especially using `static` fields is a bad approach:

Assuming you specify the controller class in the fxml, `FXMLLoader` creates a new instance of the controller class. This instance is different from the instance stored in the `controller` field so even when using

```
OverviewController.getOverviewController.returnStatusColumn.setCellValueFactory(
    cellData -> cellData.getValue().getStatusProperty());
```

after loading the fxml you wouldn't get the instance you need.

Instead I recommend using the `initialize` method of the controller class for these kind of initialisations. It's invoked by `FXMLLoader` after creating and injecting all the objects specified in the fxml.

```
public class OverviewController {

    ...

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Task, String> statusColumn;

    ...

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        statusColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getStatusProperty());
    }

}
```

---

If you ***do*** need to pass some info from an class that is not the controller, refer to the answers here [Passing Parameters JavaFX FXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml) . Better approaches than using `static` are described in the answers.